# I cannot remove numbering in this table

Tags: latex, overleaf

I use tables to write sets, data and variables for a mathematical problem in Latex. I do not want these tables to be numbered. When I create an "actual" table, the table gets the wrong number because sets, data and variables are written with the table function. Can someone help me with this?

I allready tried using `\usepackage{caption}` and `\caption*{nothing}` inside the function, but nothing happened.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    $N$ : Set of   production and consumption ports \\
                                                  \\
    $V$ : Set of vessels                              \\
                                                  \\
    $S^{A}$ : Set of possible nodes $(i,m)$         \\
                                                    \\
    $S_{v}^{A}$ : Set of nodes that can be visited by vessel $v$\\
                                                                \\
    $S_{v}^{X}$ : Set of all possible visits $(i,m,j,n)$ of vessel $v$\\
                                                                    \\
    $S_{v}^{S}$ : Set of breakpoints for the speed of vessel $v$, where $S_{v}^{S}=\{ 1,2,..,U \}$\\
                                                                    \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: If you remove the outer `\begin{table}[h]` and `\end{table}` then the table will not be numbered.

Comment: In the default classes, a table only gets a number if it has a caption. Can you please edit your question and add a compilable [mre] which reproduces your problem.

Comment: [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) defines the macro `\ContinueFloat`. If you insert the macro to a floating environment, latex is going to keep the same number.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround to prevent LaTeX from increasing a number of tables is to insert `\ContinueFloat` as the first thing in the floating environment. This macro is rather meant to split a large table into parts and keep the same number of each part to indicate that such tables form a single one.

Here is one example. Note I slightly changed your table by adding `:` as a column separator, so the table consists of two columns

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Table}\label{tab:test3}
  \begin{tabular}{r @{\ :\ } l}
    $N$ & Set of   production and consumption ports \\
    $V$ & Set of vessels \\
    $S^{A}$ & Set of possible nodes $(i,m)$ \\
    $S_{v}^{A}$ & Set of nodes that can be visited by vessel $v$ \\
    $S_{v}^{X}$ & Set of all possible visits $(i,m,j,n)$ of vessel $v$ \\
    $S_{v}^{S}$ & Set of breakpoints for the speed of vessel $v$, where $S_{v}^{S}=\{ 1,2,..,U \}$
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]\ContinuedFloat
  \caption{Table (continued)}\label{tab:test2}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{Table}\label{tab:test3}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Although even `table` environment should work as expected in the absence of the  command `caption`, I switched to `table*` environment anyway:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{l}
$N$ : Set of   production and consumption ports\\[0.5em]
$V$ : Set of vessels\\[0.5em]
$S^A$ : Set of possible nodes $(i,m)$\\[0.5em]
$S_v^A$ : Set of nodes that can be visited by vessel $v$\\[0.5em]
$S_v^X$ : Set of all possible visits $(i,m,j,n)$ of vessel $v$\\[0.5em]
$S_v^S$ : Set of breakpoints for the speed of vessel $v$, where $S_v^S=\{1,2,..,U\}$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Also, you could better use the vertical spacing between lines like `[1em]` at the end of each line, instead of empty lines between the lines with  contents.